# Card game array of objects issue

Tags: c++

I am creating a UNO game that transfers Card objects from a deck to a hand. Each player has a hand which consists of 7 random cards. The code below shows me attempting to create a player and storing the player into an array that can alter the order of turns and such. I initialized my array by Player* playerArray

```
#pragma once
#include "Player.h"
#include "DevTest.h"
#include <string>


class Game
{
private:
    int amountOfPlayers;
    //std::vector<Player> playerArray;
    Player* playerArray; //in charge of the order of turns etc
public:
    Game();
    void createPlayerArray();
    void menu();
    ~Game();
};
```

And this is where I implement my array

```
#include "Game.h"
DevTest devtest;
extern Player player;
extern Deck deck;

Game::Game()
{
}

void Game::createPlayerArray()
{

    std::string userName;
    std::cout << "Please enter the amount of players: ";
    std::cin >> amountOfPlayers;

    if (amountOfPlayers < 2 || amountOfPlayers>10)
    {
        if (amountOfPlayers < 2)
        {
            std::cout << "Sorry! Not enough players." << std::endl;
        }

        if (amountOfPlayers > 10)
        {
            std::cout << "Sorry! Too many players." << std::endl;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        playerArray = new Player[amountOfPlayers];

        std::cout << "Please enter the names of each player." << std::endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfPlayers; i++)
        {
            //Player* playerArray[i] = new Player;
            std::cout << "Player " << i+1 << ": ";
            std::cin.ignore();
            std::getline(std::cin, userName);

            playerArray[i].setUserName(userName);


            for (int i = 0; i < player.getHANDSIZE(); i++)
            {
                deck.dealCard();
            }

            player.printHand();


        }
    }
return;

}

void Game::menu()
{
    int choice;

    std::cout << "UNO" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1. Play Game" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2. Read Rules" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "3. Developer Testing" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "4. Quit" << std::endl;

    do
    {
        std::cin >> choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            std::cout << "Play Game" << std::endl;

            break;

        case 2:
            std::cout << "Read Rules" << std::endl;
            break;

        case 3:
            std::cout << "Developer Testing" << std::endl;
            devtest.testMenu();
            break;

        case 4:
            exit(0);
            break;

        default:
            std::cout << "Invalid choice. Please choose again." << std::endl;
        }
        //clear screen
    } while (choice < 1 || choice >4);
}


Game::~Game()
{
}
```

PLAYER

```
  #pragma once
#include "Deck.h"
#include <iostream>


class Player
{
private:
    int length;
    std::string username; //can indicate whos turn / wins
    static const int HANDSIZE = 7;
    Card* hand;

public:
    Player();
    void pushHand(Card deck); 
    void popHand();
    void printHand();
    int getHANDSIZE();
    std::string getUserName();
    void setUserName(std::string name);

    ~Player();
};

PLAYER.CPP
#include "Player.h"
#include "Card.h"
extern Deck deck;
//extern Game game;

Player::Player()
{

    length = 0;
    hand = new Card[HANDSIZE];

    //game.createPlayerArray();
    //new player?
}

void Player::pushHand(Card deck)
{
    //push deck object into hand
    hand[length] = deck;
    length++;
}

void Player::printHand()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Length: " << i << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Value: " << hand[i].value << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Color: ";
        deck.toString(hand[i].color);
    }
}

int Player::getHANDSIZE()
{
    return HANDSIZE;
}

std::string Player::getUserName()
{
    return username;
}

void Player::setUserName(std::string name)
{
    username = name;
}


Player::~Player()
{
}



My issue is, my array has a length of 0 even though I create the array with  `playerArray = new Player[amountOfPlayers];`
which to my understanding creates an array of player objects with a given size. My question is, how do I create an array of Player objects correctly since either this declaration is flawed or my logic somewhere else is flawed.

Also, I cannot use vectors due to the instructor's instructions.
```

Using breakpoints and Debug>Windows>Locals, I can see that my player array has a length of 0 instead of 2. I'm not sure as to what I'm doing incorrectly and a few pointers/tips would be very appreciated.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < player.getHANDSIZE(); i++)` and `player.printHand();` doesn't really make sense. What is `player` on those lines? Also your main question needs more detail - how do you know 0 players are created. Whats your input and expected output vs your actual output?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just a small reminder that such questions ( answers for Homework ) are not so well seen here by most. There is a neat post related to that ( https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: @MikeVine I've edited my post to show the functionality of Hand. The for loop basically deals 7 cards from the deck to the hand. Print hand just prints all the cards currently present in the Hand.

Comment: @JPVenson the attitude to "hw" has changed in the ten years that post has been running. even the tag has been removed.

Comment: Arrays cannot have zero size (although `new T[0]` is allowed for consistency).  You might not be *using* all the elements (at first), but they do exist.

Comment: @DavisHerring I thought that's what `playerArray = new Player[amountOfPlayers];` was doing. How would I create my array correctly?

Comment: @BobDoSomething: “I thought that’s…”—what’s “that”?  All I meant was that `new T[n]` makes *n* objects immediately (calling the default constructor for each if `T` is a class), although in many applications one maintains an additional variable to indicate how many of them (usually at the beginning) are “real”.